# ASP .Net Core web app calling a Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am quite new to ASP .Net. In fact, I am quite new to web development (I come from a Windows development background). I need to create a web app, and have decided to create the backend as a Web API. So I created the web API using ASP .Net Core 1.1, and now I am at the point where I need to create the client side. I will be developing a web app front end - again using ASP .Net Core 1.1 like I did with the backend API - and a college will develop a phone app front end. Both will connect to same Web API.

I've looked at some examples of ASP .Net Core web apps, but they all use Entity Framework to read/write to the database. My web app should not have any direct access to the database at all, but should instead interact with the database via the web API. Unfortunately I can't find any examples of an ASP .Net Core web app communicating with a Web API. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Angular, etc. And although I will definitely be learning Angular soon enough, for now, I'd like to simply have my web app controllers call the Web API instead of making EF calls to the database.... Unless, of course, that is completely wrong :)

If any one could point me in the right direction - perhaps to some sample code or something along those lines, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is truly broad, and for this reason it is difficult to answer in a specific manner.

I will try to summarize what are your best options for your project.

Creating a front-end, using a MVC application, is not wrong at all, but you have to be aware of common pitfalls you may encounter:

#### 1. Authentication/Authorization

You have to manage a mechanism for machine-to-machine authentication and authorization between your API and your front-end clients. This is not trivial. If you plan to access your API from different source (you said that there will be also a mobile app) I advice you to further explore [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/) and [OpenId](https://openid.net/connect).

In .NET Core [IdentityServer v4](http://identityserver.io) is a great implementation of both protocols. In a machine-to-machine context you should look at `Authorization Code` or `Implicit` grants for your front end.

#### 2. Abstracted data-services

The source of your data should be irrelevant. A good way to obtain this is to create Repositories or Services interfaces which are implemented by concrete classes which use libraries like [System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http) for data retrieval from your API Rest service and [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) for serialization/deserialization. Those repositories could be injected directly inside your Controllers.

A simple example could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38380423/3670737).

Comment: Thanks Federico - those are some very good points. Thanks for the sample link - that did help. And sorry for the late reply - I need to see why StackOverflow doesn't notify me when someone replies to my post